# Gnuplot plot error bars every 10 data points

Tags: gnuplot

I want to plot my data with error bars. It is to do with the syntax

```
plot "xyz.dat' u 1:2:3 w yerrorbars
```

However, since my data file has 10000 data points, plotting all error bars would make the error bars overshadow the line shape of the data. So I want to plot error bars every 10 data points. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

`plot "xyz.dat" u 1:2:3 every 10 w yerrorbars`

Also look at:

[How do I plot every nth point](http://www.gnuplot.info/faq/faq.html#x1-530004.14)